# jquery events stop after activation of a function

Tags: jquery, function, button

Newb jQuery question: I'm a bit lost as to why my jQuery functions work but stop working after I activate a function linked via a button. Everything runs as I expect it to: hovering over a row swaps add/removes the CSS and clicking on a cell prints the cell's id. But when I click on the "build table" button, the jQuery portion stops functioning.

```
<body>
<div id="cheese"></div>
<p id="printThis"></p>
<button id='buildTable'>Build Table</button>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myTable = "";
var pickRnd = 0;
var clickedValue;
buildTable();
function buildTable() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("td").click(function(event) {
            clickedValue = event.target.id;
            document.getElementById("printThis").innerHTML = "You have selected " + clickedValue;
        });
        $("tr").mouseover(function() {
           $(this).addClass("highlight");
           });  
        $("tr").mouseout(function() {
          $(this).removeClass("highlight");
          });
    $("#buildTable").click(function() {
      buildTable();
    });
    });
    myTable = "<table>";
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        pickRnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
        myTable += "<tr class='normal" + pickRnd + "' id='monsterTableRow" + i + "'>";
        for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            myTable += "<td id='td" + j + "-" + i + "'>" + j + "-" + i + "</td>";
        }
        myTable += "</tr>";
    }
    myTable +="</table>";
    document.getElementById("cheese").innerHTML = myTable;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have some error in the console (F12)?

Comment: `document.getElementById("printThis").innerHTML == $('#printThis').text()`

Comment: I don't see any error messages in the JavaScript console.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few errors ....
I have made a  fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Eh5FX/1/

```
var myTable = "";
var pickRnd = 0;
var clickedValue;
$(document).ready(function(){
function buildTable() {
   myTable = "<table>";
   for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
       console.log(" is is " + i);
       pickRnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
       myTable += "<tr class='normal" + pickRnd + "' id='monsterTableRow" + i + "'>";
       for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
           myTable += "<td id='td" + j + "-" + i + "'>" + j + "-" + i + "</td>";
      } 
      myTable += "</tr>";
  }
  myTable +="</table>";
  document.getElementById("cheese").innerHTML = myTable; 

  $("td").click(function(event) {
        clickedValue = event.target.id;
        document.getElementById("printThis").innerHTML = "You have selected " + clickedValue;
  });
  $("tr").mouseover(function() {
      $(this).addClass("highlight");
  });  
    $("tr").mouseout(function() {
      $(this).removeClass("highlight");
      });
   }

   $("#buildTable").on("click",buildTable);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That did it! I'd give ya an upvote but I don't have rep points yet. :(

Answer (score 0):

Same as above, but I have added the jquery selectors like replacing document.getElementById('printThis') with $('#printThis'). Check it out on [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XM3h8/1/)

```
var myTable = "";
var pickRnd = 0;
var clickedValue;

function buildTable() {

$('#printThis').empty();
    myTable = "<table>";
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        pickRnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
        myTable += "<tr class='normal" + pickRnd + "' id='monsterTableRow" + i + "'>";
        for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            myTable += "<td id='td" + j + "-" + i + "'>" + j + "-" + i + "</td>";
        }
        myTable += "</tr>";
    }
    myTable += "</table>";
    $("#cheese").html(myTable);

    $("td").click(function (event) {
        clickedValue = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#printThis").html("You have selected " + clickedValue);
    });
    $("tr").mouseover(function () {
        $(this).addClass("highlight");
    });
    $("tr").mouseout(function () {
        $(this).removeClass("highlight");
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    buildTable();

    $("#buildTable").click(function () {
        buildTable();
    });
});
```